# Can you distribute an app first as an enterprise app then on the app store?

Tags: ios, deployment

We are developing an app that will eventually be released onto the app store. However before then we want to first distribute a beta within the company for private use.

There are several hundred employees which is too many for the ad-hoc distribution's limit of 100, therefore I am looking into Enterprise distribution.

I came across this Apple quote regarding the Enterprise program:

> "The iOS Developer Enterprise Program is intended for companies who
>   create proprietary, in-house iOS Apps for internal deployment within
>   the company only".

The beta will be for internal deployment only, the final release will be for app store deployment only.

Are there any potential issues with this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

You will need to enroll in both the iOS Developer Enterprise Program and the standard iOS Developer Program (two different Apple Ids)